# Sharepoint Foundation 2010 and InfoPath 2010

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, infopath

Since Sharepoint Foundation does't have integration services for InfoPath, I'm looking for a simple way to allow my user (non-programmers) build InfoPath forms based on Sharepoint lists including both read and data maniputaion (ie via reapeting tables). I've seen a solution based on CAML http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc162745(v=office.12).aspx but I need something more universal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't customize list forms with InfoPath in Foundation.  List forms are browser forms, which require SharePoint Server Enterprise.

Comment: Mayby I wasn't clear. I don't want to customize sharepoint list forms in InfoPath, I need them it to create non-sharepoint forms that will use sharepoint lists as a datasource.

Answer (score 1):

While it is not a InfoPath solution, I recommend you to take a look at Pdf forms for SharePoint.

http://www.pdfsharepoint.com

Basic concept is to use Pdf forms (Adobe Reader) and integrated them with SharePoint. I know it works with SharePoint Foundation 2010.

Good luck,
Dmitry